# How to Cross check one array values into another associative multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to display `subject list`  with a checkmark value present in another array
Here I have an array: `subject list` (**name** `$fetchSubject`)

```
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [sub_id] => 1 [sub_name] => Mathematics ) [1]
> => Array ( [sub_id] => 2 [sub_name] => Physics ) [2] => Array ( [sub_id] => 3 [sub_name] => Chemistry) [3] => Array ( [sub_id] => 4
> [sub_name] => Biology ) [4] => Array ( [sub_id] => 5 [sub_name] =>
> Science ))
```

another array which stores a user-selected list (**name** `$job_sub`)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [sub_id] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [sub_id] => 7 ) [2] => Array ( [sub_id] => 8 ) [3] => Array ( [sub_id] => 9 ))
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="subjects[]" id="subject" class="form-control selectpicker " title="Select Subject" data-live-search="true" multiple="multiple">
                         <?php echo '<option value=""> Select Subjects</option>'; ?>
                        <?php
                                       foreach($fetchSubject as $sub)
                                       {
                                           if(in_array($sub['sub_id'],$job_sub))
                                           {
                                               echo '<option value="'.$sub['sub_id'].'" selected>'.$sub['sub_name'].'</option>';
                                           }else{
                                               echo '<option value="'.$sub['sub_id'].'" >'.$sub['sub_name'].'</option>';
                                           }
                                           unset($sub);    
                                       }

                                      ?>
                     </select>
```

**whole scenario is I am trying to display user data in update form that's why I need to tickmark that data which is inserted by user before**

Comment: What have you stored in $sub array?

Comment: @user3772091 i am saying $sub array ($job_sub) have a user data which I am trying to cross check

Comment: Ok, I see it. Your $job_sub array is multidimensional-array. Your in_array() code probably not processing as you thought.

Comment: @user3772091 yes you got it..

Comment: I have updated your code. Let me know if it works

Comment: @dspillai your provided solution didn't give me the desire result

Comment: @dspillai your code is still not working according to my desire but I had done.
Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

in_array operation didn't fetch values since '$job_sub' is a multidimensional array.
I have updated your code. Let me know if it's working.

```js
foreach($fetchSubject as $sub)
{
$dis =  '<option value="'.$sub['sub_id'].'">'.$sub['sub_name'].'</option>';
foreach($job_sub as $sub2) 
{                                          
if(in_array($sub['sub_id'],$sub2))
{
 $dis = '<option value="'.$sub['sub_id'].'" selected>'.$sub['sub_name'].'</option>'; 
 break;
}
}
 $echo $dis
}
```

Comment: NO NO, see if index[1] of $fetch_Subject  is at index[3] of $job_sub then it will miss. [ check if condition, you will get what I am saying]

Comment: I have updated my code. Let me know if it's working.